# Parsing json with "complicated" structure using omegastripes / VBA-JSON-parser

Tags: json, excel, vba

I like omegastripes/[VBA-JSON-parser](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) but I cannot figure out how to parse the following json-file:
https://coronavirus.ravenpack.com/data/1.3/country/US/panic.json

When simply changing the URL in the test subroutine of the provided module I get the error "JSON contains no rows".

Does anyone have experience with such a structure? The idea is to extract the name-value pairs into two columns in a Worksheet.

```
Array---Object w/ name–value pair
     ---Object w/ name–value pair
     ...
Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Option Explicit

Sub returnResults()

    Dim ret As String
    ret = getData

    Dim json As Object
    Set json = parseJSON(ret)

    Dim k As Variant
    For Each k In json("results")
        Debug.Print k("ts") & "|" & k("panic")
    Next

End Sub

Function getData() As String

    Dim httpServer As New XMLHTTP 'set reference to Microsoft WinHTTP Services

    With httpServer

        .Open "GET", "https://coronavirus.ravenpack.com/data/1.3/country/US/panic.json"

        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"

        .send

        Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4

        getData = .responseText

    End With

End Function
```

Sample of output:

```
2020-05-21 00:00:00|3.42
2020-05-20 00:00:00|3.59
2020-05-19 00:00:00|3.26
2020-05-18 00:00:00|4.86
2020-05-17 00:00:00|3.96
2020-05-16 00:00:00|4.09
2020-05-15 00:00:00|4.27
2020-05-14 00:00:00|4.04
2020-05-13 00:00:00|3.56
2020-05-12 00:00:00|3.94
2020-05-11 00:00:00|7.15
2020-05-10 00:00:00|5.92
2020-05-09 00:00:00|3.8
2020-05-08 00:00:00|3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

After adjustments this works for me too! :-)

Two things to watch out if someone wants to replicate the results. You are using "the other" JSON parser for Excel VBA: VBA-tools / VBA-JSON https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON, which is of course fine.

Running your code after importing the above VBA-tools module I do get an an error (Compile error: User-defined type not defined) in this line 'User-defined type not defined' despite having set the reference. I managed to load the json-file in a slightly different fashion.

```
Sub returnResults()

Dim req As Variant
Dim url As String
Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
url = "http://coronavirus.ravenpack.com/data/1.3/country/US/panic.json"
req.Open "GET", url
req.send

Dim ret As String
ret = req.responseText

Dim json As Object
Set json = ParseJson(ret)

Dim k As Variant
For Each k In json("results")
   Debug.Print k("ts") & "|" & k("panic")
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: my bad on not picking up that it was the other JSON parser :)